# Overloading += as compared to +

Tags: c++

I need to overload operators + and += for MyString class.

MyString.h

```
    class MyString
    {
        char* m_pStr;   
    };
```

Main

```
    MyString s1("ABC"), s2("kkk");
    MyString s("S");//GMV
    s1 +=s;
    s2 = s+s1;
    stop
```

MyString.cpp

```
MyString MyString:: operator + (const MyString & rhs){
    char * tmp = create_tmp_string(this->m_pStr, rhs.m_pStr);
    return MyString(tmp);
};

MyString & MyString:: operator += (const MyString & rhs){
    char * tmp = create_tmp_string(this->m_pStr, rhs.m_pStr);
    return MyString(tmp);
};

char* MyString:: create_tmp_string(char * one, char * two){
    int total_length = strlen(one) + strlen(two);
    char * tmp = new char[total_length + 1];
    tmp[0] = '\0';
    strcat(tmp, one);
    strcat(tmp, two);   
    return tmp;
}
```

My problem is:

```
s2 = s+s1; // Working
s1 +=s; // Not working.
```

Well, when I execute the code step by step:

```
MyString & MyString:: operator += (const MyString & rhs){
    char * tmp = create_tmp_string(this->m_pStr, rhs.m_pStr);
    return MyString(tmp);
};
```

tmp turnes out to be SABC. But s1 will not contain SABC and remains holding ABC.

Could you help me?

Comment: Just use `std::string`...

Comment: In `+=` function you return `*this` but not in `+`, because `+` operator nor same as `+=`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
MyString & MyString:: operator += (const MyString & rhs){
    char * tmp = create_tmp_string(this->m_pStr, rhs.m_pStr);
    return MyString(tmp);
};
```

should be something like this

```
MyString & MyString:: operator += (const MyString & rhs){
    char * tmp = create_tmp_string(this->m_pStr, rhs.m_pStr);
    *this = MyString(tmp);
    return *this;
};
```

assuming your operator= is working correctly.

But really there is an easier way to do it. Just write one operator in terms of the other, for instance write operator+ using operator +=

```
MyString operator+(const MyString& x, const MyString& y)
{
    MyString res = x;
    res += y;
    return res;
}
```

or you could do it the other way around

```
MyString& MyString::operator+=(const MyString& x)
{
    *this = *this + x;
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `operator+=` should return `*this` instead of a local variable.

Comment: And `operator+` could easily be implemented in terms of `operator +=`.

Answer (score 3):

`operator+=` is typically a member function; it modifies its left-hand argument and returns a reference to `*this`. `operator+` is typically a non-member function that returns a newly-created object; it can be implemented easily with `operator+=`, so it doesn't need to know any implementation details.

Answer (score 2):

in `operator +=` you should rewrite value of *this.

```
MyString & MyString:: operator += (const MyString & rhs){
    char * tmp = create_tmp_string(this->m_pStr, rhs.m_pStr);
    // seems you own m_pStr. In this case 
    // don't forget, you should make deep copy in copy constructors and 
    // delete in destructor.
    delete this->m_pStr;
    this->m_pStr = tmp;
    return *this;
};
```

After that you may write `operator +` using `operator +=`

```
MyString operator + (const MyString& rhs){
    MyString copy = *this;
    return copy += rhs;
}
```

Comment: @H2CO3: No, rewrite and return.  But the rewrite is much more important.